# Reordenar ListBox com Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, .net, order, listbox

Bom dia amigos! Tenho uma *ListBox* na minha aplicação *C# Windows Form*. Gostaria de uma forma de usar os eventos `Drag-n-Drop` para **reordenar** os itens dentro da *listbox* da maneira que o usuário deseja. Basicamente eu gostaria de arrastar uma linha da *listbox* até outra linha de destino dentro da mesma *listbox*, reordenando-as.

EDIT: Não tenho muitas idéias de como fazer, não trabalhei ainda com drag and drop, porém através de exemplos na internet eu fui montando o meu código. Não funciona.

EDIT2: Código atualizado e funcionando!

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace projetodetestes
{
    public partial class testedragdrop : Form
    {
        public testedragdrop()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void testedragdrop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.SelectedItem == null) return;
            this.listBox1.DoDragDrop(this.listBox1.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = listBox1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            int index = this.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(point);
            if (index < 0) index = this.listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            object data = listBox1.SelectedItem;
            this.listBox1.Items.Remove(data);
            this.listBox1.Items.Insert(index, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostre o que você já conseguiu fazer e apresente um [MCVE]...

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o erro está na linha:

```
object data = listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Altere para:

```
object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)); 
//Caso não seja string altere, no meu caso é string
```

Comment: bom dia amigo, tentei alterar essa linha e ainda não funciona.

Comment: Não sei qual o tipo dos itens da sua `ListBox`, mas altere para o tipo correto que funcionará. Na minha `ListBox` inseri os items `a`, `b`, `c` e `d` e funcionou com o `string`.

Comment: Esta funcionando! obrigado.